# Push Notifications PushEvent data is null

Tags: firebase, encryption, push-notification, service-worker, event-listener

I've setup Push notifications using Firebase and can't send custom data.

I've also tried the [PyFCM](https://github.com/olucurious/PyFCM) library but the data is still null. From what I've found, the [payload requires encryption](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/web-push-encryption) but I'm not sure how to implement this.

**How can I encrypt the push data in python or send custom data via push notifications?**

I'm hoping to run the event_handler.py as a service, poll a MySQL database for new notifications and send a push notification to that user.

I'm already saving the user's registration_ids, I just need to be able to send data via push notifications.

**service-worker.js**

```
 self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  if (event.data) {
    console.log(event.data.text());
  }
  console.log('Received a push message', event);

  if (event.title) {
    var title = event.title;
  } else {
    var title = 'New message.';
  }

  var body = 'You have received a push message.';
  var icon = 'img/logo.png';
  var tag = 'simple-push-demo-notification-tag';

  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {
      body: body,
      icon: icon,
      tag: tag,
    })
  );
});
```

I can send a Push Notification using the following:

**notification_handler.py**

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'key=AAAAl...',
}

data="""{
   "to" : "fk1jL...",
   "data" : {
     "title" : "hi there",
     "body" : "new push message",
   },
 }"""


response = requests.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', headers=headers, data = data)
```

However, when the push notification is received, the data is null in the console output:

```
Received a push message  PushEvent {isTrusted: true, data: null, type: "push", target: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope, currentTarget: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope, …} bubbles: false cancelBubble: false cancelable: false composed: false currentTarget: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope {clients: Clients, registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration, onactivate: null, onfetch: null, oninstall: null, …} data: null defaultPrevented: false eventPhase: 0 isTrusted: true path: [] returnValue: true srcElement: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope {clients: Clients, registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration, onactivate: null, onfetch: null, oninstall: null, …} target: ServiceWorkerGlobalScope {clients: Clients, registration: ServiceWorkerRegistration, onactivate: null, onfetch: null, oninstall: null, …} timeStamp: 0 type: "push"
__proto__: PushEvent
```

Comment: As per [python request docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), the data argument of requests.post should be a dictionary, not a string

Comment: Thanks @jro, using the json parameter to encode the payload automatically, the data still comes through as null